# Find the vectors that span the subspace of $W$ in $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Question:** Find the vectors that span the subspace of $W$ in $R^3$.
$$W = \{\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}, 2x-y+3z=0 \}$$

I'm not very sure how to go about solving this problem. I know that the cross product of the vectors that span $W$ has to be a vector orthogonal to a normal vector of the plane $W$. Vector $<2, -1, 3>$ is the easiest normal vector to find. But then I'm unsure what to do next.

I'd much appreciate it if someone could show me how this is done. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First find one non-zero vector perpendicular to the given normal $(2,-1,3)$; this is very easy (just substitute numbers in). I'll take $(-1,1,1)$ here. Then the second vector is the cross product of this with $(2,-1,3)$:
$$(-1,1,1)×(2,-1,3)=(4,5,-1)$$
The three vectors are mutually orthogonal, so any two vectors span a plane orthogonal to the third vector. Concretely, $(-1,1,1)$ and $(4,5,-1)$ span $W$.

Answer (score 0):

$2x-y+3z=0$ implies that $y=2x+3z$, if $(x,y,z)\in W$, $(x,y,z)=(x,2x+3z,z)=x(1,2,0)+z(0,3,1)$ implies that $(1,2,0)$ and $(0,3,1)$ span $W$.